# emacs cancel the last action ,the ctrl+g is not very effective

Tags: emacs, ctrl, gud

Emacs usually use <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> to cancel the operation ,but when i use the GUD mode to debug a program ,the <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> is usually not working so well as i expected.
For example, if i wanna to set a break point at the source test.cpp, line 223,
if i input 
"b test.c:" ,then i use the TAB to auto complete it then will try to list all the possible result , then the emacs cannot respond to any input.
if i use <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> to cancel this, the result continue to output all result to the screen, this may take a long time.
is there a way to cancel this action more effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> is for cancelling Emacs commands, but that output is coming from the debugger that's being run in the comint buffer. The Emacs command has already completed, it just sent the TAB to the debugger process.

Try <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, which sends an interrupt to the subprocess. However, it's possible that the subprocess has already finished sending the list of results, and it's all in the pty buffer.